# Entity Framework dose not create database in the localdb

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC, and right now I am trying to work out the example demonstrated in professional Asp.Net MVC 4 by Galloway J and others, in this example I have to do the following :

1. create 3 classes: Album, Genre, Artist
2. create DBContext class called MusicStoreDB
3. create a controller call it store manager.

in the scaffolding options I used MVC controller with read/ write actions and views, using Entity framework

I also set an Initializer to recreate the database always on application start

but when running the solution no database created, what could be the problem I have tried lot of suggestions, even reinstalling the sql server 2008 R2 and, VS 2012 but it dose not work.

this is the global.asax file

```
Imports System.Web.Optimization
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
        Database.SetInitializer(Of MusicStoreDB)(New DropCreateDatabaseAlways(Of MusicStoreDB)())
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth()
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the MusicStoreDB class

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class MusicStoreDB
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Albums() As DbSet(Of Album)
        Get
        End Get
        Set(value As DbSet(Of Album))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Genres() As DbSet(Of Genre)
        Get
        End Get
        Set(value As DbSet(Of Genre))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Artists() As DbSet(Of Artist)
        Get
        End Get
        Set(value As DbSet(Of Artist))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DbContext specifies the proper connection string:

```
public class MyNewContext : DbContext
{
    public MyNewContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

It is `DefaultConnection` by default, but make sure you changed yours to `MusicStoreDB` if you want to use your new connection string. I have left mine at default thus far and deployed to Azure effortlessly.

You should be able to use Entity Framework in a new project without setting up any new connection strings. It "just works" using SQL Express.

I'm willing to bet you have a database existing if you connect to `(localdb)\v11.0` in SSMS or elsewhere.

Post your global.asax and DbContext if you continue to have problems.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but I have posted the global.asax and the MusicStoreDB class

Comment: Do you receive an error when debugging the website, or are you simply reporting that you can't find the database yourself? There's a difference, and it's important at the moment. Please post a specific error. You've just shown me that you are using the wrong connection string, so I don't think you're looking in the right SQL instance either.

Comment: I only have one instance on my sql server the default one, I can't find the SQLEXPRESS instance

Comment: Please confirm what you have tried. Did you change the "DefaultConnection" in the DbContext to "MusicStoreDB" instead? Are you receiving any errors? You are still being ambiguous. By default Visual Studio creates MDF files in the App_Data folder and attaches them to LocalDb, and you have not shown why it would be any different for you.

Comment: the only error I have is that when I navigate to the /MusicStore I receive is "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source"

Answer (score 0):

So I faced this same problem today and it turns out that I presumed EF automatically checks on application start whether that DB exists or not; to say the least my hope was way to ambitious.

The EF will only create the DB if it doesn't exist once you invoke the DB context. For example when you first run the application, if on the landing page you don't instantiate the DB context nothing happens.

For the Music Store example if you are following the book, navigate to (using your own port number of course) "http://localhost:34295/StoreManager", that controller's action should instantiate the DBContext if you have been following the book.

Hope this helps anyone who got a little lost like me!